# Finding difference between two very large lists

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have two very large lists, one is 331991 elements long, lets call that one a, and the other is 99171 elements long, call it b. I want to compare a to b and then return a list of elements in a that are not in b. This also needs to be efficient as possible and in the order that they appear, that is probably a given but I thought I may as well throw it in there.

Comment: Does uniqueness of elements in the list matter?

Comment: Obligatory: What have you attempted?

Comment: 1. try naive approach like `[x for x in a if x not in b]` 2. benchmark 3. fast enough? If not, try something else and goto 2.

Comment: Things like: [x for x in set(b) if x not in set(a)] and even something basic like [set(a)-set(b)],

Comment: and the uniqueness of elements should matter in the sense that if an element appears multiple times in either of them, then those words should not appear in the new list. Also if you are asking if an element can appear more than once in the new list, yes it can.

Comment: using `a=[random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(331991)]` and similar for `b`. I got `10 loops, best of 3: 152 ms per loop` Fast enough? Really crappy test though ;-) What does `a` and `b` contain?

Comment: they contain strings, just words. In this case a is a book and b is part of a dictionary

Comment: 'Dictionary' like a book or like a Python hash structure?

Comment: First: make clear, what you really want to do. You have asked similar question (intervals of numbers to process) about an hour ago and when I was going to post complete answer, I found, you have removed the question.
Second: elaborate your question first on your own - as others have suggested - you shall show what you have tried already.
Third: Write your reactions in full sentences, as you can see, other reactions may come in between.
Good luck with stack overflow.

Comment: I literally just made this account so I can ask this question, sorry for any confusion

Comment: "if an element appears multiple times in either of them, then those words should not appear in the new list" -- I think "either" should have been "both".

Comment: Yes you're right spaceghost, once again sorry for the confusion

Comment: spaceghost, when I say dictionary I mean like a book

Comment: after this long discussion. can you add small examples of what you want to see?

Comment: lets say that a=['a','b','c','d','e'] and b=['a','b','c','f','g'], it should give me back ['d','e']

Comment: Please edit your question to add the points raised in the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done in O(m + n) time where m and n correspond to the lengths of the two lists:

```
exclude = set(b)  # O(m)

new_list = [x for x in a if x not in exclude]  # O(n)
```

The key here is that sets have constant-time containment tests. Perhaps you could consider having `b` be a set to begin with.

See also: [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

---

Using [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282507/finding-difference-between-two-very-large-lists/19283567#comment28553608_19282507):

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> b = ['a','b','c','f','g']
>>> 
>>> exclude = set(b)
>>> new_list = [x for x in a if x not in exclude]
>>> 
>>> new_list
['d', 'e']
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume:

```
book = ["once", "upon", "time", ...., "end", "of", "very", "long", "story"]
dct = ["alfa", "anaconda", .., "zeta-jones"]
```

And you want to remove from book list all the items, which are present in dct.

Quick solution:

```
short_story = [word in book if word not in dct]
```

Speeding up searches in dct: turn dct into set - this has faster lookups:

```
dct = set(dct)
short_story = [word in book if word not in dct]
```

In case, the book is very long and does not fit into memory, you may process it word by word. For this, we may use a generator:

```
def story_words(fname):
"""fname is name of text file with a story"""
  with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
      for word in line.split()
        yield word

#print out shortened story
for word in story_words("alibaba.txt"):
  if word not in dct:
    print word
```

And in case, also your dictionary would be far too large, you would have to give up speed and iterate also over content of dictionary. But this I skip for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way converting `b` to a set, then filtering elements from `a` that are not present:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse

a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = ['a','b','c']
c = list(ifilterfalse(set(b).__contains__, a))
# ['d', 'e']
```