# Ruby - is efficient way to find the difference between two very large arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I have a problem concerning efficiency and algorithms when it comes to finding the difference between two very large arrays. I'm hoping someone with a good understanding of algorithms can point me to the right direction in how to solve this as my current implementations is taking an extremely long amount of time.

Problem:

I have two very large arrays. One contains a list of emails that have invalid domain names and the other is a mixed list that I need to check against the first array.

```
accounts_with_failed_email_domains = [279,000 records in here]

unchecked_account_domains = [149,000 records in here]
```

What I need to do is go through the list of `unchecked_account_domains` and then compare each entry to see if there is a match in the `accounts_with_failed_email_domains`.  I need to insert all matches between the lists in a separate array to be processed later.

How can I efficiently write something that can quickly check through these accounts. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
unchecked_account_domains = [really big array]
unchecked_account_domains = unchecked_account_domains.sort

accounts_with_failed_email_domains = [another huge array].sort

unchecked_account_domains.keep_if do |email|
  accounts_with_failed_email_domains.any? { |failed_email| email == failed_email }
end

# Count to see how many accounts are left
puts unchecked_account_domains.count
```

This above implementation has been running forever. Here is the second attempt which still proved not to be any better.

```
unchecked_account_domains = [really big array]
unchecked_account_domains = unchecked_account_domains.sort

accounts_with_failed_email_domains = [another huge array].sort

unchecked_account_domains.each do |email|
  accounts_with_failed_email_domains.bsearch do |failed_email| 
     final_check << email if email == failed_email 
  end
end

# Count to see how many accounts are left
puts final_check.count
```

`bsearch` seemed to be promising, but I'm pretty sure I'm not using this correctly.  Also, I tried looking into this question [comparing large lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282507/finding-difference-between-two-very-large-lists) but this is in `python` and I can't seem to find a Ruby equivalent for `set`.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you can use `Array#-`:

```
result = unchecked_account_domains - accounts_with_failed_email_domains
```

Comment: This is a good approach if `==` is the comparison you're really after

Comment: It says in the Ruby docs that the implementation of array-difference uses similar hashing techniques to Set so this should work pretty efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @ilya. This did the trick but I should still probably look into algorithms though :)

Comment: @DanRubio, you are welcome. It is just _already_ implemented solution. Look at source of this method if you are more interested in algorithms.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't have a new solution here, because the good answers were already taken.  However, I wanted to see if there was a performance difference between the two code-based solutions.

This answer is a benchmark to highlight any performance differences in the use of `Array#-` and two uses of `Set#include?`.  The first `Set#include?` benchmark always does the set conversion, and the second converts once and keeps the set for subsequent searches.

Here's the code that runs each test 50 times:

```
require 'set'
require 'benchmark'

string = 'asdfghjkl'
Times = 50

a = 279_000.times.map {|n| "#{n}#{string}" }
b = 149_000.times.map {|n| "#{n*2}#{string}" }

puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION
puts "============================================================"
puts "Running tests for trimming strings"

Benchmark.bm(20) do |x|
  x.report("Array#-:")      { Times.times {|n| a - b } }
  x.report("Set#include? #1:") do
    Times.times do |n|
      d = []
      c = Set.new(b)
      a.each {|email| d << email if c.include?(email) }
    end
  end
  x.report("Set#include? #2:") do
    c = Set.new(b)
    Times.times do |n|
      d = []
      a.each {|email| d << email if c.include?(email) }
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the results:

```
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-darwin14]
============================================================
Running tests for trimming strings
                           user     system      total        real
Array#-:              12.350000   0.250000  12.600000 ( 13.001546)
Set#include? #1:      16.090000   0.330000  16.420000 ( 17.196469)
Set#include? #2:       8.250000   0.100000   8.350000 (  8.726609)
```

Clearly, if you just need a single differences comparison, use the `Array#-` approach.  However, if you need to do this type of thing multiple times, pre-converting the set makes a tremendous difference and performs better than `Array#-`.  The cost of converting the Array to a Set is fairly high (comparatively), but once you have a Set, it performs the difference comparison much more quickly.

Comment: This is a good breakdown of what's been outlined across answers

Answer (score 1):

A `Set` would be useful here if you know the array contains unique items (or you're not bothered by losing duplicates - which I don't think you are), so simply take your big array and do:

```
require 'set'
unchecked_account_domains = [really big array]

accounts_with_failed_email_domains = Set.new([another huge array])
final_check = []

  unchecked_account_domains.each do |email| 
     final_check << email if accounts_with_failed_email_domain.include?(email)  # .include? on a set is in O(1) look up time 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array of failed emails to a set (I think the Ruby command is `.to_set`, read about it in the Ruby docs). Then check each of the unchecked emails against the set using `.include?`.

The reason it runs forever is it runs through the entire or much of the list for each check. The set class ought to hash the list, making queries much much faster.